# iCloud storage maxed drive before update to Monterrey

Tags: icloud, recovery, monterey

Preface: I'm a Windows power user with Unix experience. I thought I could help a friend work through an upgrade from high Sierra to Monterrey on a MacBook Air 2015.

Unfortunately, the update ended up stuck in a boot loop. When I went into disk viewer in recovery mode, I found that the primary hard drive was ~90% full of shared iCloud junk from my friend's other iCloud users. Obviously, I could go in and rm a bunch of directories, but I'm worried that doing so would delete those files in the synced computers.

How do I safely delete enough iCloud files to finish the Monterrey upgrade? Currently, I'm planning on removing my friend from the iCloud shared account so that file changes don't permeate to the other computers.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by:

1. We disconnected the faulty computer from the shared iCloud just in case errors propagated
2. We [booted into recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255) and inserted a 64GB USB drive (I believe we actually had to mount it inside terminal.)
3. Using the terminal, we navigated inside the Monterrey update app and found the `createinstallmedia` command, then formatted the usb drive as update media. See [this Apple support post](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372).
4. This let us delete the update app from the computer, as it was runnable from the USB stick. This is important because the app itself takes up ~12gb of space *aside* from the space needed by the update process. It's free real estate if you can shunt the update to a usb stick.
5. I used the `find` command to locate large files and target them for inspection/deletion, but in the end, you're looking to just delete enough files that Monterrey can install. I mainly was deleting image backups, other people's documents, and cache files, since they're unlikely to be immediately needed or irrecoverable.
6. Finally, once I had deleted enough files, I went back to the "main" page of recovery mode and it asked me if I wanted to install Monterrey.

Good luck on your own update!